# UIPrintInteractionController returns UIPrintUnknownImageFormatError

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf, printing

I'm trying to print pdf document being downloaded through NSURLConnection like this

```
    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    NSData *PDFData = urlConnection.receivedData;
    if  (pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:PDFData] ) {
        pic.printingItem = PDFData;
        ...
        [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
```

and I receive UIPrintUnknownImageFormatError in the completionHandler despite the pdf is good and is opened by any pdf-viewer. What could be wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

this trick helped:

```
    [receivedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSData *PDFData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```